# c# LINQ create query for tie breaker for calculating positions

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

My current output looks like this:

```
ContestId | Points | Position | Timestamp
   1         90          1        2018-06-18 12:00:00
   1         80          2        2018-06-18 12:15:00
   1         75          3        2018-06-18 12:30:00
   1         75          3        2018-06-18 12:25:00
   1         72          5        2018-06-18 12:40:00
```

The tiebreaker is the timestamp.
The data is retrieved from a SQL database using c# MVC.  I would like the output to look like:

```
ContestId | Points | Position | Timestamp
   1         90          1        2018-06-18 12:00:00
   1         80          2        2018-06-18 12:15:00
   1         75          3        2018-06-18 12:25:00
   1         75          4        2018-06-18 12:30:00
   1         72          5        2018-06-18 12:40:00
```

This is the Model:

```
public class ContestResult
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ContestId { get; set; }
        public int Points { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the query that generates the output:

```
pointScores = contestResults.Where(a => a.contestId == contest.id)
             .Select((v, i) => new ContestResult
             {
                 ContestId = v.ContestId,                                                            
                 Points = v.Points,
                 TimeStamp = v.TimeStamp,
                 Position = db.ContestResults
                            .Where(a => a.ContestId == contest.id)
                            .Count(p => p.Points > v.Points) + 1
             }).ToList();
```

How do I iterate through the positions that are tied and re-number the rank position based on the timestamp?

Comment: is this a text file or datatable or what?

Comment: please provide a minimal ,complete and verifiable example so we can help you in ur issue

Comment: You're showing the output, but not the code structure. There's no way to answer this objectively, only to guess what is it that you might want.

Comment: Do you mean `.OrderBy(x => x.position).ThenBy(x => x.timestamp)`?

Comment: The data is retrieved from a SQL database using c# MVC.

Answer (score 0):

After some researh, I added additional conditions to the Count method.

```
pointScores = contestResults.Where(a => a.contestId == contest.id)
             .Select((v, i) => new ContestResult
             {
                 ContestId = v.ContestId,                                                            
                 Points = v.Points,
                 TimeStamp = v.TimeStamp,
                 Position = db.ContestResults
                            .Where(a => a.ContestId == contest.id)
                            .Count(p => p.Points > v.Points || 
                            (p.Points == v.Points && p.TimeStamp < v.TimeStamp)) + 1
             }).ToList();
```

The only issue that I have is that if I add additional fields that I can use to validate a condition, it always evaluates to False, which then does not increment the position value.